# If a sequence $(x_n)$ in $U$ converges to some $x\notin U$, what can we say about the sequence $(f(x_n))$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $U\subset \mathbb R$ is open and let $f: U\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Suppose we have a sequence $(x_n)$ in $U$ such that $x_n$ converges to some $x\notin U$.Then can we say anything about the sequence $(f(x_n))$?

This might be a basic question, but I can't think of an answer. Here the problem is that $f(x)$ is not defined as $x\notin U$. So I can't say $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. I think $(f(x_n))$ at least has a converging subsequence, but can't prove. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

---

PS: Not a homework question. I just need clarification the concept of continuity.

Comment: Basically you need to show that if $x\notin U$ is a cluster point of $U$ then $f(x)$ is also a cluster point of $f(U)$.

Answer (score 1):

Ιf $x$ is an accumulation point of $U$ and $f$ has a limit $L$ at $x$ then $f(x_n) \to L$ by the sequential characterization of the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, consider f(x) = 1/x and g(x) = x, defined in U = (0,1).